# Create a new Ruby on Rails application using MySQL instead of SQLite

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create my Rails application with MySQL, because I like it so much. How can I do that in the latest version of Rails instead of the default SQLite?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

If you already have a rails project, change the adapter in the `config/database.yml` file to `mysql` and make sure you specify a valid username and password, and optionally, a socket:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db_name_dev
  username: koploper
  password:
  host: localhost
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Next, make sure you edit your Gemfile to include the mysql2 or activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (if using jruby).

Comment: This is helpful; as the other answers just use the generator.  This answer works for adding MySQL to an app after it's already been created, either to replace an existing (e.g. SQLite) DB or to add a secondary database.  Also, mysql2 seems to be the go-to gem these days for Rails.

Comment: you'll also have to update the Gemfile; remove `gem 'sqlite3'` and add `gem 'mysql2'`

Answer (score 270):

Normally, you would create a new Rails app using

```
rails ProjectName
```

To use MySQL, use

```
rails new ProjectName -d mysql
```

Answer (score 62):

For Rails 3 you can use this command to create a new project using mysql:

```
$ rails new projectname -d mysql
```

Answer (score 26):

Go to the terminal and write:

```
rails new <project_name> -d mysql
```

Answer (score 22):

If you have not created your app yet, just go to cmd(for windows) or terminal(for linux/unix) and type the following command to create a rails application with mysql database:

`$rails new <your_app_name> -d mysql`

It works for anything above rails version 3. If you have already created your app, then you can do one of the 2 following things:

1. Create a *another_name* app with mysql database, go to cd *another_name*/config/ and copy the database.yml file from this new app. Paste it into the database.yml of *your_app_name* app. But ensure to change the database names and set username/password of your database accordingly in the database.yml file after doing so.

OR

1. Go to cd *your_app_name*/config/ and open database.yml. Rename as following:

development:
  adapter: mysql2 
  database: db_name_name
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

Moreover, remove gem 'sqlite3' from your Gemfile and add the gem 'mysql2'

Answer (score 13):

If you are using rails 3 or greater version

```
rails new your_project_name -d mysql
```

if you have earlier version

```
rails new -d mysql your_project_name
```

So before you create your project you need to find the rails version. that you can find by

```
rails -v
```

Answer (score 12):

```
rails -d mysql ProjectName
```

Answer (score 11):

```
rails new <project_name> -d mysql
```

OR

```
rails new projectname
```

Changes in config/database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db_name_name
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 11):

Create application with -d option

```
rails new AppName -d mysql
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$ rails --help
```

is always your best friend

usage:

```
$ rails new APP_PATH[options]
```

also note that options should be given after the application name

rails and mysql

```
$ rails new project_name -d mysql
```

rails and postgresql

```
$ rails new project_name -d postgresql
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use the switch -D instead of -d because it will generate two apps  and mysql with no documentation folders.

```
  rails -D mysql project_name  (less than version 3)

  rails new project_name -D mysql (version 3 and up)
```

Alternatively you just use the `--database` option.

Answer (score 6):

If you are creating a new rails application you can set the database using the -d switch like this:

```
rails -d mysql myapp
```

Its always easy to switch your database later though, and using sqlite really is easier if you are developing on a Mac.

Answer (score 6):

In Rails 3, you could do

```
$rails new projectname --database=mysql
```

Answer (score 6):

Just go to rails console and type:

```
rails new YOURAPPNAME -d mysql
```

Answer (score 4):

On new project, easy peasy:

```
rails new your_new_project_name -d mysql
```

On existing project, definitely trickier. This has given me a number of issues on existing rails projects. This kind of works with me:

```
# On Gemfile:
gem 'mysql2',  '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5' # copied from a new project for rails 5.1 :)
gem 'activerecord-mysql-adapter' # needed for mysql..

# On Dockerfile or on CLI:
sudo apt-get install -y  mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that mysql gem is installed, if not? than type following command in your console

```
gem install mysql2
```

Than create new rails app and set mysql database as default database by typing following command in your console

```
rails new app-name -d mysql
```

Comment: you want to add the gem to Gemfile instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Use following command to create new app for API with mysql database**

```
rails new <appname> --api -d mysql


  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

**database.yml**

```
# MySQL. Versions 5.1.10 and up are supported.
#
# Install the MySQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-hashing.html
#
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: localhost
  database: database_name
  username: username
  password: secret

development:
  <<: *default

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="mysql2://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
```

**Gemfile**:

```
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

you first should make sure that MySQL driver is on your system if not run this on your terminal if you are using Ubuntu or any Debian distro

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

and add this to your Gemfile

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.16'
```

then run in your root directory of the project

```
bundle install
```

after that you can add the mysql config to config/database.yml as the previous answers