# using mysql with ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby

Please can anyone guide me on how to use mysql with ruby on rails.

What are the steps that i should follow to use mysql with ruby on rails.

What are the gems needed to install mysql.

Thanks in advance

amit rawat

Comment: What rails version? What operating system?

Comment: Similar question discussed below:

[how-do-i-create-a-new-ruby-on-rails-application-using-mysql-instead-of-sqlite][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585/how-do-i-create-a-new-ruby-on-rails-application-using-mysql-instead-of-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

That's obvious - `gem "mysql"`