# How to get Ruby on Rails (Rails v4, Ruby v1.9.3) to work with MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here are the places I have already tried to find the answer:
[tutorials point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-database-setup.htm), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585/create-a-new-ruby-on-rails-application-using-mysql-instead-of-sqlite), [another stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409761/installing-mysql2-gem-for-ruby-on-rails-with-mac-osx-10-6), and [the official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

I still have no idea what I am doing wrong. After I have configured the database.yml correctly, I try to create the project and this is the error I get:

"Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.13), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.13'` succeeds before bundling."

**Why can't I find mysql2 v0.3.13?**

OS: Windows 7
Rails: 4.0.0
Ruby: 1.9.3
DevKit installed

**Errors that I have encountered**
`$ bundle exec rails s
Could not locate Gemfile`

`$ bundle
Bundler::GemfileNotFound`

```
`$ gem install mysql2
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        c:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=c:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
extconf.rb:37:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)


Gem files will remain installed in c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.13 for inspection.`
```

Comment: I have installed the latest version of MySQL which is 5.x or 6. I don't know how to find out. Rails keeps saying that it can't find mysql2 gem.

Comment: This is what is in my Gemfile: `# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'`. When I run bundle this is the output:`Bundler::GemfileNotFound`

Comment: Close terminal and open again. `cd` to the correct directory. check ruby version (`ruby -v`). check rails version `bundle exec rails -v`. check `Gemfile` exists. run `bundle`. run `bundle exec rails s`. if any of these checks fail, edit the question and tell us exactly what is wrong. copy-paste actual errors that you see.

Comment: None of those worked and I pasted the errors on an edit. Should there be more that I need to post?

Comment: Please see how to format text as code. The text you pasted is not readable otherwise.

Comment: If none of those things worked, you need to get them working before doing anything else.

Comment: I got them to work! It changed mysql2 versions on me. Now it installed version 0.2.6 instead of 0.3.13. What does that mean?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38384/discussion-between-casey-and-zabba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Close terminal and open again.
- `cd` to the correct directory.
- check ruby version (`ruby -v`).
- check rails version `bundle exec rails -v`.
- check `Gemfile` exists.
- run `bundle`.
- run `bundle exec rails s`

Comment: It turned out that I wasn't in the right directory and I had to run all of these commands once I was. What does `bundle exec rails s` do?